# Regex match string with possible spaces

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a RegEx that will find the string

```
02075517[
```

However this string sometimes has spaces so I would need it to match

```
020 75517[
```

and

```
0207 5517[
```

and

```
020 7551 7[
```

etc.

I've tried using this site here: http://www.regexr.com/ but can't quite get there.

Thanks very much

Ed

Comment: remove all the spaces then match with the numbers. No need for any regex. Simply use `equals`

Comment: Sorry perhaps I should have explained I am using regex with a tool called AJC Grep that searches word documents for strings

Answer (score 1):

You can define a group to be matched.
`([0-9 ]+\[)` will match multiple numbers or spaces followed by a square bracket.
See http://www.regexr.com/39rhh

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because if the document contains 020a7551[ then it matches the 7551[ but I want to reject it because although there is 020 there is something that isn't a space i.e. 'a'

Comment: Would there be an expression to match 020 + anything that is a number or space + 7[

Comment: Yes, simple put it at the beginning: `(020[0-9 ]+\[)` http://www.regexr.com/39rht

Comment: or if you want a 7 in front of the square bracket: `(020[0-9 ]+7\[)` http://www.regexr.com/39ri0